# Wordpress remove_action doesn't remove the hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

I want to remove the sorting options from my shop page [here](http://wildartdevon.co.uk/) using

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```

Edit: I've tried different priority values, including 10, which is the key for the array containing the action in the outpur below. Still no joy!

It works fine on other sites, but not this one (using Nova WP theme, child of Storefront).

When I add

```
global $wp_filter;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $wp_filter['woocommerce_before_shop_loop'] );
echo '</pre>';
```

to my archive-product.php the output is this:

```
array(5) {
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["wc_print_notices"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(16) "wc_print_notices"
      ["accepted_args"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    ["woocommerce_catalog_ordering"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(28) "woocommerce_catalog_ordering"
      ["accepted_args"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  [9]=>
  array(1) {
    ["storefront_sorting_wrapper"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(26) "storefront_sorting_wrapper"
      ["accepted_args"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  [20]=>
  array(1) {
    ["woocommerce_result_count"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(24) "woocommerce_result_count"
      ["accepted_args"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  [30]=>
  array(1) {
    ["storefront_woocommerce_pagination"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(33) "storefront_woocommerce_pagination"
      ["accepted_args"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  [31]=>
  array(1) {
    ["storefront_sorting_wrapper_close"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(32) "storefront_sorting_wrapper_close"
      ["accepted_args"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Please help?

Comment: I see the remove options works good for me. http://wildartdevon.co.uk/basket/ Try incognito mode for a moment !

Comment: I want it to work on the home page (which is set as "shop.") The output above display whrn I add the var_dunp to the relevent template. Incognito makes no difference...What I don't get is that the action is clearly shown on the hook, yet doesn't get removed. Is it possibly to do with the priority value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I've finally found an answer to this [here](http://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-remove-default-sorting-dropdown/). It seems that the "storefront" theme behaves differently to other themes in this regard. What is needed to remove the sorting drop down is:

```
// remove default sorting dropdown in StoreFront Theme
add_action('init','delay_remove');
function delay_remove() {
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop',  'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
}
```

as opposed to the more obvious-seeming

```
// remove default sorting dropdown
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```